iFrame breaks master page in C# ASP.NET
When I use <iframe> in a content area of a webform, the master page gets all messed up.
I have reduced it down to a simple:
<iframe src=""> </iframe>

The master page in the containing webform (parent) gets total bashed.  I also tried to do this programmatically with a PlaceHolder control.  Same results. This is running on .NET 4.5.2.

"Totally bashed" is not an adequate problem description. All we can do is speculate - it could be anything from a malicious script within the iframe breaking-out and clobbering the DOM of the parent page (browsers only protect against cross-site scripting, not same-site scripting) - or the prescence of the iframe invalidates some critical CSS style rule selectors that make bad assumptions about the element structure; maybe you aren't correctly HTML-encoding your output? (always use <%: over <%= unless you know the expr is safe, etc)
